# Parse does not return on first query attempt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment control that determines what is loaded into the table view. I load the table for index 0 in viewDidLoad and it works fine. The segment control is  'selected' to index 0 via storyboard. When the index is switched to index 1 I get the alert message I set "No items owned" and it has me stay at index 0. When I click index 1 for the second time, it finds the items and loads the table I want for index 1. Why does the query for getOwnedCosmetics not return anything the first time the segment is changed to index 1?  I print cosmeticIdOwned and it returns [ ]. The second time the array is filled with the objects.

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class SkinsTableViewController: UITableViewController  {


var cosmeticTracker = "Skins"
var cosmeticName = [String]()
var cosmeticImage = [PFFile]()
var cosmeticRarity = [String]()
var cosmeticId = [String]()
var owned = "Owned"
var cosmeticIdOwned = [String]()


@IBOutlet var cosmeticTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var seg: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch seg.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        getAllCosmetics(cosmetic: cosmeticTracker)  
    case 1:
        getOwnedCosmetics(cosmetic: cosmeticTracker)   
    default:
        break;
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

getAllCosmetics(cosmetic: cosmeticTracker)


}

@objc func getOwnedCosmetics (cosmetic : String){
    if PFUser.current() != nil {
    let query = PFQuery(className: (cosmetic + owned))
    query.whereKey("theUser", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId as Any)     
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {         
         print(error)  
        } else if let objects = objects {
         self.cosmeticIdOwned.removeAll()
            for object in objects {
                    self.cosmeticIdOwned.append(object["theCosmetic"] as! String)
            }
        }
    })
        if cosmeticIdOwned.count > 0 {
    getOwnedCosmeticsQuery()
        }
        else {
            self.displayAlert(title: "No items owned", message: "Add \(cosmeticTracker) to your colection")
            seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        }
    }
    else {
         self.displayAlert(title: "Unable to retrieve data", message: "Please sign in")
        seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
}


func getOwnedCosmeticsQuery (){
    let queryOwned = PFQuery(className: cosmeticTracker)
    queryOwned.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: cosmeticIdOwned as [AnyObject])
    queryOwned.order(byAscending: "Rarity")
    queryOwned.addAscendingOrder("Name")
    queryOwned.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in  
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let objects = objects {       
            self.cosmeticName.removeAll()
            self.cosmeticImage.removeAll()
            self.cosmeticId.removeAll()
            self.cosmeticRarity.removeAll()
            for object in objects {
                self.cosmeticName.append(object["Name"] as! String)
                self.cosmeticImage.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                self.cosmeticId.append(object.objectId as String!)
                self.cosmeticRarity.append(object["Rarity"] as! String)

                self.cosmeticTable.reloadData()

                if self.cosmeticIdOwned.count > 99 {
                    self.getOwnedCosmeticsQueryTwo()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

}
```

I would like to note if I populate cosmeticIdOwned with an item in viewDidLoad. It will make it to getOwnedCosmeticsQuery and find the item, even though it is not actually 'owned'. When I click the segment for getOwnedCosmetics for the second time, it runs getOwnedCosmeticsQuery with the correct objects it found from getOwnedCosmetics.

Comment: Please post concise, minimal examples, not your entire code. Concerning your problem: you update the UI from the background thread which can cause the problem you describe -- the data is fetched but not correctly shown. To fix, wrap all UI update code in your query callbacks in `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: I have removed a lot of the code I posted. I have tried that and it did not work. The data is not being fetched on the first attempt. I print cosmeticIdOwned and it returns [ ]. The second time the array is filled with the objects.

Comment: Your problem description sounds like the queries are different. You can compare the queries to make sure: add a member variable (`var firstQuery: PFQuery?`) and in `getOwnedCosmetics` set it on first call/compare it on second call (`if let firstQuery = firstQuery { assert(firstQuery == query, "D'oh!") } else { firstQuery = query }`) -- of course just for testing, to be removed afterwards. (Btw -- you still should correctly handle the UI update, using the `main` queue -- not doing so will eventually lead to further problems.)